# What part of asyncio is concurrent? Would like implementation details

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

The description of the asyncio module is:

> This module provides infrastructure for writing single-threaded
>   concurrent code using coroutines, multiplexing I/O access over sockets
>   and other resources, running network clients and servers, and other
>   related primitives.

I have been reading about the new and extraordinary asyncio python module/package/whatever. I understand there is the python GIL and so the asyncio properly fits well with the GIL since (the intention is) you manage things with an event loop on a single thread. So what is concurrent? Well it seems that the I/O seems to be concurrent. I believe I/O operations are handled by the operating system. So in the internals of asyncio, does it write a concurrent C-extension that utilizes functions given by the operating system?

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 7):

In asyncio, single-threaded IO concurrency is achieved by combining many concepts:

```
future -------------------+---------+
                          |         |
generator ---> coroutine -+-> task -+-> base event loop -+-> selector event loop
                                                         |
select ---> selector ------------------------------------+
```

However, it is possible to achieve the same purpose without futures, as proven by [curio](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio):

```
generator ---> coroutine -+-> task -+-> kernel
                                    |
select ---> selector ---------------+
```

---

### Links

[Standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/):

- [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)
- [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)
- [selector](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html)
- [native coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-def)

[Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html):

- [asyncio coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)
- [asyncio future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#future)
- [asyncio task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task)
- [base event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)
- [selector event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.SelectorEventLoop)

[Curio](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

- [curio coroutine](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#coroutines)
- [curio task](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#tasks)
- [curio kernel](https://curio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#the-kernel)

Comment: curio is asyncio2