# Does __await__ need to be a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I want to implement an awaitable and noticed that `__await__` 'needs' to be a generator.

From [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression):

> An object with an `__await__` method returning an iterator.
>
> ...
>
> Objects with `__await__` method are called Future-like objects in the rest of this PEP.
>
> It is a TypeError if `__await__` returns anything but an iterator.

In my experience, before `await` was a statement, `yield from` was used together with coroutines implemented as generators. Nowadays python (I'm using 3.5) has asynchronous methods using the `async def` syntax. I therefore consider the `yield from` syntax as old/deprecated.

So I broke out the interpreter to see how/if this works:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __await__(self):
...         yield from (asyncio.sleep(1).__await__())
...         return 'spam'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.run_until_complete(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 467, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 294, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 240, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 585, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __await__
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__await__'
```

So it appears `asyncio.sleep` doesn't have the `__await__` method. It also feels very awkward to use this `yield from` syntax.

So I decided to try with the `async` syntax, just to see if it would work:

```
>>> class A:
...     async def __await__(self):
...         await asyncio.sleep(1)
...         return 'spam'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> 
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.run_until_complete(a)
'spam'
```

It actually seems to work! So now I'm wondering, does the `__await__` method really **need** to be a generator using the `yield from` syntax?

---

Edit: When adding a level of indirection, so the awaitable is used in an `await` statement the problem becomes apparent:

```
>>> async def test():
...     return await A()
... 
>>> loop.run_until_complete(test())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
TypeError: __await__() returned a coroutine
```

It actually thus needs to be returning a generator like so:

```
class A:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        return 'spam'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So it appears `asyncio.sleep` doesn't have the `__await__` method

True, but it doesn't have to have one to be awaitable. The [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) says that `__await__`, if present, needs to return an iterator, not that `await` will only work on objects that define `__await__`. In fact, it explicitly documents that the argument to `await` can be *one of*:

- A *native coroutine* object returned from a native coroutine function.
- A *generator-based coroutine* object returned from a function decorated with `types.coroutine()`.
- An object with an `__await__` method returning an iterator.
- An object defined in C providing the Python/C equivalent of the `__await__` special method.

> So now I'm wondering, does the `__await__` method really need to be a generator using the yield from syntax?

If you actually have an `__await__` method, it does need to return an iterator.

Comment: Since you didn't explain why it needs to return an iterator I added my findings in an edit to my question.

Comment: @siebz0r *Since you didn't explain why it needs to return an iterator* - I understood the question to ask whether it is true that `__await__` must return a generator (it is), and whether it is a requirement for an awaitable object to implement `__await__` (it is not). As for **why** `__await__` needs to return an iterator, that is a separate topic, likely already [covered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42917109/1600898) on SO.

Comment: I figured, I thought of explicitly asking "does it need to return an iterator and if so why" but I figured it would make sense as the "why" would be the explanation for the first question. I guess I made the assumption here so I'm not blaming you or anything. I simply wasn't expecting an answer that stated "because the docs said so", since that was already clear.

Answer (score 5):

In order to work in an `await` expression, `__await__` does not need to be a generator. However, certain operations are only available if the result of `__await__` support the generator interface.

Namely, it is not possible to `send` values or `throw` exceptions into an iterator-`__await__`. Only `None` can be "sent" to an iterator-`__await__`, as if [`generator.__next__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.__next__) were used.

---

Let's consider a simple `Awaitable` that returns an iterator from its `__await__`.

```
class Iter:
    """Basic iterator that yields the same value"""
    def __next__(self): return 1
    def __iter__(self): return self

class IterAwait:
    """Awaitable that uses an iterator for __await__"""
    def __await__(self):
        return Iter()
```

We can check that they implement the desired interfaces:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Awaitable, Iterator, Generator
>>> isinstance(IterAwait(), Awaitable)
True
>>> isinstance(IterAwait().__await__(), Iterator)
True
>>> isinstance(IterAwait().__await__(), Generator)
False
```

In order to see how this interacts with `await`, we wrap it in a coroutine:

```
async def iter_await():
    await IterAwait()
```

Every operation we perform on `iter_await` with the full coroutine/generator interface is forwarded by `await` to our iterator-`__await__`. This allows to study how the iterator-`__await__` receives signals:

```
>>> test_iter = iter_await()
>>> test_iter.send(3)         # 0. does it appear like a coroutine?
TypeError: can`t send non-None value to a just-started coroutine
>>> test_iter.send(None)      # 1. must initialise just-started coroutine
1
>>> test_iter.send(None)      # 2. repeatedly use the underlying iterator
1
>>> next(test_iter)           # 3. do we expose the iterator?
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not an iterator
>>> test_iter.send(3)         # 4. can we send non-None values?
AttributeError: 'Iter' object has no attribute 'send'
>>> test_iter = iter_await()  # we just broke the coroutine...
>>> test_iter.send(None)      # ...need a new one
1
>>> test_iter.throw(KeyError) # 4. can we throw Exceptions?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in iter_await
KeyError
```

As can be seen, `await` can handle an iterator-`__await__`, but does not forward all operations. However, some are translated and some are handled early.

- It is always possible to `.send(None)`, which is translated to a bare `__next__()`. (1, 2)
- The coroutine does not magically expose `.__next__` (3) and cannot translate `.send` with a value either (4).
- It is possible to `.throw` an exception, but `await` handles it early in the coroutine.

Note that `await` uses the `throw` and `send` method as available. If the result of `__await__` implements `send` but not `throw` or vice versa, the functionality present is used. Only `__next__` is mandatory.