# Python coroutines: Release context manager when pausing

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

Background: I'm a very experienced Python programmer who is completely clueless about the new coroutines/async/await features. I can't write an async "hello world" to save my life.

My question is: I am given an arbitrary coroutine function `f`. I want to write a coroutine function `g` that will wrap `f`, i.e. I will give `g` to the user as if it was `f`, and the user will call it and be none the wiser, since `g` will be using `f` under the hood. Like when you decorate a normal Python function to add functionality.

The functionality that I want to add: Whenever the program flow goes into my coroutine, it acquires a context manager that I provide, and as soon as program flow goes out of the coroutine, it releases that context manager. Flow comes back in? Re-acquire the context manager. It goes back out? Re-release it. Until the coroutine is completely finished.

To demonstrate, here is the described functionality with plain generators:

```
def generator_wrapper(_, *args, **kwargs):
    gen = function(*args, **kwargs)
    method, incoming = gen.send, None
    while True:
        with self:
            outgoing = method(incoming)
        try:
            method, incoming = gen.send, (yield outgoing)
        except Exception as e:
            method, incoming = gen.throw, e
```

**Is it possible to do it with coroutines?**

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducable? What is `self` and `function`? How do you call `generator_wrapper` and why does it have `_` as first parameter?

Comment: If that's confusing, you can just ignore the example. The functionality I want is described by the paragraph above it.

Comment: To learn about coroutines, async, await, and the event loop, I highly recommend watching [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4) by David Beazley. The lecturer creates a simple event loop from scratch in front of live audience, precisely showing the interplay between coroutines and the event loop. (Don't be put off by the lecture's use of the older `yield from` syntax, `await` is just a very thin syntactic sugar over `yield from`, as explained in MisterMiyagi's answer.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Coroutines are built on iterators - the [`__await__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__await__) is a regular iterator. This allows you to wrap the underlying iterator in yet another iterator. The trick is that you must *unwrap* the iterator of your target using its `__await__`, then *re-wrap* your own iterator using your own `__await__`.

The core functionality that works on instantiated coroutines looks like this:

```
class CoroWrapper:
    """Wrap ``target`` to have every send issued in a ``context``"""
    def __init__(self, target: 'Coroutine', context: 'ContextManager'):
        self.target = target
        self.context = context

    # wrap an iterator for use with 'await'
    def __await__(self):
        # unwrap the underlying iterator
        target_iter = self.target.__await__()
        # emulate 'yield from'
        iter_send, iter_throw = target_iter.send, target_iter.throw
        send, message = iter_send, None
        while True:
            # communicate with the target coroutine
            try:
                with self.context:
                    signal = send(message)
            except StopIteration as err:
                return err.value
            # communicate with the ambient event loop
            # depending on the signal, we need a different send method
            try:
                message = yield signal
            except BaseException as err:
                send, message = iter_throw, err
            else:
                send = iter_send
```

Note that this explicitly works on a `Coroutine`, not an `Awaitable` - `Coroutine.__await__` implements the generator interface. In theory, an `Awaitable` does not necessarily provide `__await__().send` or `__await__().throw`.

This is enough to pass messages in and out:

```
import asyncio


class PrintContext:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit via', exc_type)
        return False


async def main_coro():
    print(
        'wrapper returned',
        await CoroWrapper(test_coro(), PrintContext())
    )


async def test_coro(delay=0.5):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return 2

asyncio.run(main_coro())
# enter
# exit via None
# enter
# exit <class 'StopIteration'>
# wrapper returned 2
```

---

You can delegate the wrapping part to a separate decorator. This also ensures that you have an actual coroutine, not a custom class - some async libraries require this.

```
from functools import wraps


def send_context(context: 'ContextManager'):
    """Wrap a coroutine to issue every send in a context"""
    def coro_wrapper(target: 'Callable[..., Coroutine]') -> 'Callable[..., Coroutine]':
        @wraps(target)
        async def context_coroutine(*args, **kwargs):
            return await CoroWrapper(target(*args, **kwargs), context)
        return context_coroutine
    return coro_wrapper
```

This allows you to directly decorate a coroutine function:

```
@send_context(PrintContext())
async def test_coro(delay=0.5):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return 2

print('async run returned:', asyncio.run(test_coro()))
# enter
# exit via None
# enter
# exit via <class 'StopIteration'>
# async run returned: 2
```

Comment: Excellent answer. A minor quibble: _regular iterator_ is probably a bit optimistic. Although an iterator might work for simple cases, your actual example expects `__await__` to return a _generator_ (or an object mimicking it with duck typing), as it calls the [generator methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) `send` and `throw`, neither of which are available on an ordinary iterator. I think you should also call `close()` the `target_iter` once you're done, otherwise its `finally` clauses will not run or will run later than necessary.

Comment: @user4815162342 Interestingly enough, the specification for ``__await__`` only requires an iterator. For example, ``def __await__(self): return iter([1, 2, 3, 4])`` is valid and works. However, event loops (and the shown class) expect *coroutines*, not *awaitables* - a coroutine's ``__await__`` implements the generator interface. There is no need to explicitly close ``target_iter``, since the wrapper will go on until ``target_iter`` throws ``StopIteration`` - this only happens when the underlying iterator is done.

Comment: Agreed about closing `target_iter` and `StopIteration`. As for event loops expecting coroutines, I don't think that's true for asyncio. `Future` is an example of an awaitable that is not a coroutine, and is accepted everywhere. The only place that requires a coroutine is `create_task`, which is specifically designed to drive a coroutine.

Comment: @user4815162342 You are correct. ``Future`` is not a coroutine, though ``Future.__await__`` provides a generator. It seems like the minimum expected functionality is a generator-interface-``__await__``.

Comment: Do you think an `__await__` that is just an iterator wouldn't work in asyncio? I think it should work, but it will simply not support features like propagating cancellation, which requires `.throw(exc)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 ``asyncio`` works by using ``send`` and ``throw``. Whatever you feed to ``asyncio`` *must* implement the generator interface, at least for ``__await__``. In principle, you can use an iterator-``__await__`` somewhere down the stack, but ``asyncio`` will choke when trying to communicate with it. Basically an iterator-``__await__`` is a one-way communication, but ``asyncio`` expects bidirectional. You can find my writeup on the implications of iterator-``__await__`` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190525/does-await-need-to-be-a-generator/56114311#56114311

Comment: *Whatever you feed to asyncio must implement the generator interface, at least for __await__* I don't think this is true. [A simple test](https://pastebin.com/mv65Bjjd) shows that you can pass an awaitable implemented with an iterator to asyncio. This is [explicitly supported](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/410b85a7f701be280eb15b0ca4fe116e86f1d008/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L634) in `ensure_future`. You can also pass such awaitables to combinators like `gather`, all of which call `ensure_future` internally, so that works just fine too.

Comment: *Basically an iterator-`__await__` is a one-way communication, but asyncio expects bidirectional.* Asyncio only sends `None` to the coroutine, which is why it works with an iterator just fine. The only case when something more is needed is when `CancelledError` is injected into the coroutine, and that is handled by `_wrap_awaitable` (whose `yield from`, I suppose, simply ignores the exception it can't pass to the iterator it was delegated to).

Comment: @user4815162342 Alright, "whatever you feed to asyncio's async interface should *really* emulate the coroutine interface if you want full functionality, but of course asyncio lugs around an incredible array of sync/legacy wrappers that are poorly separated into public/private interface and you can freely use those if you feel like it, especially if you do not communicate with the event loop at all". ``asyncio.run`` does an explicit type check for coroutines/generators, by the way.

Comment: Hmm. The only functionality I'm aware of that wouldn't work is cancellation. Is there something else I'm missing? Supporting non-generators in `__await__` is extremely useful for things like Cython or Python/C implementations of awaitables, so I don't see it as a bad thing and don't really understand the sentiment underlying your comment. (Perhaps I'm misreading you, but you sound frustrated by this part of asyncio design.) I'm aware of `asyncio.run()` requiring a coroutine, and it's vaguely annoying because something as simple as `asyncio.run(gather(a(), b()))` doesn't work as a result.

Comment: @user4815162342 The full coroutine interface is basically ``send(None)`` and ``throw``. Not supporting cancellation is not some small detail, it is half the interface; notably one that sets async apart from threads. Not picking a consistent communication interface means that *all* ``asyncio`` material, including answers, documentation, and code, is ripe with special casing of things that may-or-may-not-work. This is exemplified by basic async operations like ``gather`` being a mess of 70 lines that does not even fit a common async interface - compared to, say, a 4 line coroutine in ``trio``.

Comment: You're making a good point, iterator-based `__await__` fundamentally doesn't support cancellation, which is a bummer. Cancellation can still be supported with custom awaitables using duck typing. The `yield from` in `_wrap_awaitable` will automatically [make use](https://pastebin.com/RMPr2MY4) of the `throw` if the inner iterator provides it, thus allowing injection of `CancelledError`. This can be (and likely is) used by Cython, and then we're no longer talking about pure-iterator `__await__`, but about duck-typed-generator one, which is a different beast.

Comment: I think you can replace `return err.args[0] if err.args else None` with `return err.value`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for the hint! Tested and verified it with the docs, ``err.value`` is valid on all Python versions that support ``async``.

Comment: No problem! That occurred to me while reviewing your code in preparation for the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64395754/1600898). While the problems this answer solves occur rarely, when they are this is truly an elegant solution for what would otherwise be an almost insurmountable issue.

Comment: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66695548/1600898) use of the technique from this answer.